# Is it possible to call objective C application delegate method from Swift class of the same project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm merging my `Swift` project with already existing `Objective-C` code. I need to call some important methods of Swift class from objective C app delegate. I tried all methods given in net, but it was no use. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. make sure you've marked this with `@objc`

Comment: did you use #import Project-Swift.h in app delegate?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry i have done that. but still having error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but with some limitations.

You can use only classes which inherited from NSObject, with public attribute and marked with @objc. At Objective-C code you should import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" file which generated by compiler.

Here is an example of Swift class:

```
import Foundation

@objc public class ExampleClass: NSObject {
    @objc public var someInstanceProperty = "Property"

    @objc public func someFunction() {
        print("Some function")
    }
}
```

Notice that this class inherited from NSObject and have @objc and public attributes. After command+B you can take a look at generated bridge header through Assistance editor:
[image: bridge-header]

Then you should import the bridge header at your Objective-C class.

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

And then you can use your Swift class at Objective-C code like any other Objective-C class:

```
__auto_type const someClass = [ExampleClass new];
[someClass someFunction];
NSLog(@"%@", someClass.someInstanceProperty);
```

Here is an additional information from Apple:
[Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)

Comment: Its really amazing. working for me . thanks a lot bro

Comment: Marked bro. thanks for all your support. i have a doubt. here is the solution to cal swift method from objective c app delegate. how to call objective c AppDelegate method from swift?

Comment: 1. You can create a bridging header by choosing File > New > File > [operating system] > Source > Header File.
2. Import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift
3. In Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting has a path to the bridging header file
4. Any public Objective-C headers listed in the bridging header are visible to Swift